# discord.py How to set a kick command such that only an administrator can use it?

Tags: python, discord.py

Here is my code -

```
@client.command()
@client.command.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await member.kick()
    await ctx.message.add_reaction("✅")
    await ctx.send(f"{member.name} has been kicked by {ctx.author.name}!")

    await log_channel.send(f"{ctx.author.name} has kicked {member.display_name}")
```

It shows the following error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Gacha/Desktop/Python Bot/bot.py", line 56, in <module>
    @client.command.has_permissions(administrator=True)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'has_permissions'
```

I dont know why its showing this, I saw someone using this and it worked for him. ;-;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its `@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)` instead of `@client.command.has_permissions(administrator=True)`

And I wonder where you saw someone else using it

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now! And I do not really remember exactly where I saw that 

Comment: No biggie, glad that helped 